# How to show a title of document window without icon?

Tags: cocoa

Now I drag a file to the app icon in the dock, this app is based on document . I found that no little image on the left of window title after the app is run and the mainwindow is open . but when I drag a file to the dock icon before the app run and use this method to run the app , a little image on the left of window title to show the file ,just like the xcode etc.
Now I want to show the little image both way or not to show the little image both way , How to do ? I think that it maybe the window property based on document , but I don't know how to fix it ? Thanks![alt text http:///Users/jinxin/Desktop/Mydocument.png](http:///Users/jinxin/Desktop/Mydocument.png)

---

I used the `[mainWindow setTitle:tmp];`, but icon still appear. when I used `setTitleWithRepresentedFilename:` I found that both icon and window title name both are modify, in the document class I overload the `-(void)displayName;` so I want to the window title is fixed anytime.

Answer (score 2):

If you just use `-setTitle:`, no icon. If you use `-setTitleWithRepresentedFilename:` you get the icon.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I found the result:

1.

```
[[window standardWindowButton:NSWindowDocumentIconButton] setImage:image]
```

2.

```
- (BOOL)window:(NSWindow *)sender shouldPopUpDocumentPathMenu:(NSMenu *)titleMenu
{
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the Cocoa docs for `NSWindow` (under `representedURL`):

```
[[window standardWindowButton:NSWindowDocumentIconButton] setImage:image]
```

Maybe setting it to nil will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the answers above but they didn't work. This worked for me in Mavericks:

[How to hide file icon in window titlebar of NSDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372521/how-to-hide-file-icon-in-window-titlebar-of-nsdocument/25389571#25389571)